# No installation candidate for libopenmpi2

Tags: 18.04, mpi

I've been trying to install [openFOAM](https://openfoam.org/download/6-ubuntu/) on 18.04 and get the following error after `sudo apt-get install openfoam6`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 openfoam6 : Depends: libopenmpi2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried running `sudo apt-get install libopenmpi2` and get:

```
E: Package 'libopenmpi2' has no installation candidate
```

I'm not really familiar with this kind of issue, but I was under the assumption that if I can find something [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libopenmpi2) then it should be installable?

Any ideas on what to try to fix it?

Comment: Run `sudo add-apt-repository universe` and try installation again

Comment: Thanks @Kulfy, unfortunately I think that's already added: "sudo add-apt-repository universe"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely [issue 1817](https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/-/issues/1817#note_49023), which as the final note says is *"quite weird"* in that it appears to be an installation order issue. The suggested fix (please read the issue for more detail):

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-all libopenmpi-dev
$ sudo apt install libopenmpi-dev
```